# Electron-builder How can I add environment variable to My APP

Tags: electron, electron-builder

My package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "start-wine":"cross-env NODE_ENV=wine electron .",
        "buld-wine":" electron-builder build -c build/wine.json",
        "start-sheitc":"cross-env NODE_ENV=sheitc electron .",
        "buld-sheitc":"  electron-builder build -c build/sheitc.json"
},
```

when I start my app,I will add the NODE_ENV to it

```
const myDev = () => {
  return process.env.NODE_ENV;
}
```

this is easy to run the app from different evn in my Webstrom

So if I using electron-builder to build it ,I also want to run the app in the  NODE_ENV.

I try to search the way but no result.

Comment: Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Comment: Do I understand it right that you need this variable not for the building process but for the binary? Would setting the variable in your commandline before running the built binary in that commandline be an option for what you want to do?